# java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "": No address associated with hostname

Tags: android, android-studio, flatmap

I m trying to do a post on server with an object of type Attendance when I m connected to a certain WiFi network. The method sentAttendanceListFromCacheObservable it s irrelevant here. When postAttendance method inside the flatMap is called it always enter on onError with the message

> java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "": No address
>   associated with hostname.

here is the postAttendance method.

```
 public void postAttendance(String date, String checkIn, String checkOut, String breakTime, boolean finishActivity) {
    view.showProgress(view.getStringFromResId(R.string.wait));
    Attendance attendance = new Attendance();
    attendance.setDate(date);
    attendance.setCheckInTime(checkIn);
    attendance.setCheckoutTime(checkOut);
    attendance.setBreakTime(DateUtils.getNumberOfMinutesFromHourStringWithDifferentFormat(breakTime));
    //aici
    addSubscription(attendanceManager.sendAttendanceListFromCacheObservable()
            .flatMap(response -> {
                return attendanceManager.postAttendance(attendance);
            })
            .doOnNext(response -> {
                if(response != null) {
                    sessionManager.setGeofenceStatus("");
                }
            })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .unsubscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .doAfterTerminate(() -> {
                view.hideProgress();
            })
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<Attendance>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "", e);
                    view.handleError(e, true);
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(Attendance response) {
                    if (finishActivity) {
                        view.finishActivity();
                    } else {
                        view.postAttendanceSuccessfully(response);
                    }
                }
            }));
}
```

and here is the method that gives me the error. .flatMap(isReachable -> {} is never called.

```
 public Observable<Attendance> postAttendance(Attendance attendance) {
    return Observable.fromCallable(() -> InetAddress.getByName(BuildConfig.PING_URL).isReachable(TIMEOUT))
            .flatMap(isReachable -> {
                if (isReachable) {
                    return apiService.postAttendance(sessionManager.getAccessToken(), attendance)
                            .doOnError(throwable -> FileUtils.writeFile(TAG + " " + throwable.getMessage()))
                            .doOnNext(r -> FileUtils.writeFile(TAG + " attendance successfully sent to server: date: " + attendance.getDate() + " checkin: " + attendance.getCheckInTime() + " checkout" + attendance.getCheckoutTime()))
                            .flatMap(serverAttendance -> getUserMonthlyActivity(attendance.getDate())
                                    .map(userMonthlyActivities -> serverAttendance));
                } else {
                    UserAttendanceDB userAttendanceDB = new UserAttendanceDB();
                    userAttendanceDB = UserAttendanceDB.convertUserAttendanceInUserAttendanceDB(userAttendanceDB, attendance);
                    userAttendanceDao.insert(userAttendanceDB);
                    return Observable.empty();
                }
            });

}
```

Retrofit

```
 private boolean configured = false;

private HttpLoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor;
private CookieInterceptor cookieInterceptor;
private HeadersInterceptor headersInterceptor;

private Retrofit.Builder retrofitBuilder;

protected OkHttpClient.Builder httpClientBuilder;
private OkHttpClient httpClient;

@Inject
public ApiServiceProvider(Retrofit.Builder retrofitBuilder, OkHttpClient.Builder httpClientBuilder,
                          HttpLoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor, CookieInterceptor cookieInterceptor,
                          HeadersInterceptor headersInterceptor) {

    this.httpClientBuilder = httpClientBuilder;
    this.retrofitBuilder = retrofitBuilder;
    this.loggingInterceptor = loggingInterceptor;
    this.cookieInterceptor = cookieInterceptor;
    this.headersInterceptor = headersInterceptor;
}

private void buildClient() {
    httpClientBuilder.addInterceptor(headersInterceptor);
    httpClientBuilder.addNetworkInterceptor(loggingInterceptor);
    httpClientBuilder.addInterceptor(cookieInterceptor);

    httpClient = httpClientBuilder.build();
}

@Override
public ApiService get() {
    if (!configured || httpClient == null) {
        buildClient();
        configured = true;
    }

    Retrofit retrofit = retrofitBuilder.client(httpClient).build();

    return retrofit.create(ApiService.class);
}
```

Comment: You probably have an issue building the request url (looks like it's empty). Can you post your Retrofit initialisation here, please? Also, try debugging the value of BuildConfig.PING_URL, could be empty

Comment: I m using the BuildConfig.PING_URL in few other places and it works well. I also edited with the retrofit initialisation

Comment: Looks like device does not has connectivity

Comment: The isReachable should be false then and insert a new object into DB

Comment: @CristiDumitrache if you are using the HttpLoggingInterceptor you are able to verify which/if the request is being made on logcat. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the value of TIMEOUT? is in seconds or milliseconds?

```
 * @param   timeout the time, in milliseconds, before the call aborts
 * @return a {@code boolean} indicating if the address is reachable.
 * @throws IOException if a network error occurs
 * @throws  IllegalArgumentException if {@code timeout} is negative.
 * @since 1.5
 */
public boolean isReachable(int timeout) throws IOException {
    return isReachable(null, 0, timeout);
}
```

TIMEOUT is a generic name so be sure that is imported correctly.

Comment: Thank you very much. Timeout value was 15. I changed it now